Next.js & Stripe Elements - Invalid API Key provided
I have a next.js app with Stripe Elements running on AWS Amplify. Everything works great locally but on live i get an error An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error. which in the logs relates to "Invalid API Key provided"
I've tracked the issue down to this file
import "server-only";

import Stripe from "stripe";

const dotenv = require("dotenv"); 
dotenv.config();

export const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY as string, {
  apiVersion: "2024-04-10",
});

The STRIPE_SECRET_KEY isn't loading on live, I've added the ENV var but it doesn't seem to be picked up via process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY if I hard code the key it works fine.

This doesn't appear to be an issue with the Stripe SDK, but rather an issue with your environment variable management. You'll need to work with your host to understand how these should be set such that you can reference them as needed in your code.

@NolanH yeah you're right seems to be an issue with AWS and how they handle env vars! Worked first time on vercel
